# How to specify % of Equity and Leverage in this strategy.entry() function?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Here's an example code for the strategy. Titles, overlay removed for better readability.

```
strategy(initial_capital=1000, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100)

strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when = short_entry)
```

How to include ***Percent of Equity*** and ***Leverage*** into it?

For example:

- *5% Percent of Equity*
- *10x Leverage*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", initial_capital=1000, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 5, margin_long=10, margin_short=10)
```

Comment: Oh, great, thank you! :) And which attribute is the 5% Percent of Equity? 10-10-10 everywhere so I couldn't decode it. :D

Comment: `default_qty_value = 5`